# Does a catalog "Adjustable Chopper" IC exist?

Tags: integrated-circuit, pwm, power-electronics

I am looking for an IC with 4 key pins: GND (0V), PWR (e.g., 3.3V), HVSW
(e.g., 60V), and CTRL.
CTRL uses an external component (probably R or C, or even an analog voltage
source) to set the pulse frequency (e.g., 2 MHz) at which the IC then switches an
integrated output NMOS/NPN on and off (e.g., with 50% duty cycle such that the
final result is that HVSW is repeatedly pulled low for 1us and then floated between
0V and 60V for 1us).

I imagine that such an IC, if existing, probably has an additional CTRL2 pin
to adjust the duty cycle, but I don't really need that.

I could even work without any CTRL pin since I could design my final product
with almost any common frequency.  Jitter/accuracy, at whatever frequency is
available, is also not important as long as it doesn't vary by more than 20%
(so, I do not need a crystal).  I am not using feedback to change the
frequency.

I am fairly sure that I am going to need a 555 timer, its large set of external
components, and a power NMOS to get this done.  Or, is there an easier way?
Is there an IC available which merges some sort of timer and power transistor?

Comment: Have you considered (ab)using something like an integrated boost switching regulator? A superficial look at the internal block diagram of a [LM5002](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm5002.pdf?HQS=dis-dk-null-digikeymode-dsf-pf-null-wwe&ts=1620323150037) for example makes me think that you could maybe hook up the FB and/or COMP pins in a creative way to force a fixed duty-cycle...

Comment: You must specify load RLC or impedance but any Schmitt trigger Astable oscillator driving a logic level FET open drain or NPN open collector with a pot to offset bias Rb/Rf= <10. Capiche ?

Comment: What is the peak current through the switching transistor?

Comment: @AnalogKid I didn't want to specify this since I felt there might be no one-chip solution for any peak current spec.  But, since you asked, I personally want the switch to carry 0.5A (and also keep HVSW below 0.5V at this 0.5A).

Comment: Biiiiiiig difference between driving a transistor that sinks 0.5 A and one that sinks 200 A, particularly if you need edge times of less than 100 ns.  HEY, that's another thing - edge (rise and fall) times - ???

Answer (score 1):

This oscillator uses a pot much lower than the feedback and series R so it does not affect frequency as much.

- you can use 3.6V logic or 5.5V CMOS logic families and vary the duty cycle +/- 22% with these values.
- some offset may occur with temperature effects on thresholds.
- [SIM. Here](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjATCCsCmC0YwgOwQHQQJwBZpgGYccA2MABhSwA4ZyY6YEkAoAY3CygjU%20-Nr0C6As2SJ0JFHnxEUJLPmLJy6cuTAsATiB5RItMF3ARB4depYAHPicPE74J%20RYBzRxAg4POen5YA7rq8BsH8goG2oUbhIC4A8mGOBND6pnFxLGDSjjHgJPSe3sgU6nHoWIoW1TXIAEqwAM4Alo0ALgCGAHZssFkh6XnRDvQoIMIE4yIZfujQIABqAPYANp2ufWDUk3kQAkl7ZqrzYOjIGFATme67IcamR9r5hfu7%20-TQ1U96uvsEBCRfmZ-i42uMAUCQL4XmYVJIcNQUAQUBosCgwNAaGBvKoSFIqApoCjSChtsUygATWAAMw6AFc1m4oWUiszCr4Zk9oSBqEJUjy-OYvnVxvzeeNyN5xfRkAQauYQAUZnNItzxdy8i5fJNiIZ0kTAZrwCgAPoULwm8hmgrqCAmhQVSo0TFUSryU2qCxgS0mu3ZE0EFhLRWOIQkRHeeaeixokjQEgQKPgFhAA)
- alternatively you can use a DAC on a fixed R ratio bias that shifts the duty cycle of the triangle wave feedback and do the same thing.

**Required**: a chip to make 50% d.c. 2MHz with +/- 20% PWM for a 60Vdc signal chopper by Resistor or Voltage control.

**Simplistic solution below**, using sig.gen with 60Vdc bias using 3.3V = Vdd

[image]

With unity current gain, a common base drive on NPN would be much faster.

Comment: But, is there a chip which combines the oscillator and power transistor? My question seeks your operation with just one chip, one pot, and one battery.

Comment: @bobuhito Asking for recommendations for a specific product are off-topic on this site. If you want to **design** something then Tony has given you some suggestions.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson I didn't ask for a recommendation among options - I asked if there even exists an option.

Comment: @bobuhito How would an answer of just "yes" been helpful to you? When someone asks "Is there a chip...?" the obvious and natural response is to provide an **example** of such a chip, which amounts to a **recommendation** for that chip. I think you did indeed want a recommendation.

Comment: What is the peak current through the switching transistor?

Comment: @AnalogKid. What is 70V/100k?  Neglecting capacitance TBD. With unity gain a common base would be faster on std transistors

Comment: His problem is not the PWM but the Miller and stray capacitance switching 2MHz at 60V https://tinyurl.com/yj2jdckn

Comment: @bobuhito A dual comparator (LM393 comes to mind) can be made to  do this task, by making the Schmitt trigger of one section, and using the other section to drive the open-collector transistor.

Comment: I was asking the TS/OP.  I don't see any load description.

Comment: It’s the load capacitance that matters, consider a JFET Op Amp with guarded tracks. 3pF max